# Swiper React Mouse-wheel Scrolling and Keyboard Control Not Working

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Using the mouse-wheel or keyboard to control the sliding in SwiperJs for React doesn't work. I can't seem to find anything on it and following Swiper API docs doesn't help either.

Using
react: 17.0.1
swiper: 6.4.11

There's a sandbox setup of it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-vertical-mousewheel-13rk6?file=/src/index.js:0-715)

```js
const App = () => {
  const slides = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  return (
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView={2}
      keyboard={{ enabled: true }}
      direction="vertical"
      mousewheel
    >
      {slides.map((slide) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={slide}>
          <h1>Slide</h1>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Please get SwiperCore module to do below:

```
import SwiperCore, { Keyboard } from 'swiper';
```

and add following line of code:

```
SwiperCore.use([Keyboard]);
```

This should have the keyboard working.

Comment: To make it work you also have to add the following prop:                 keyboard={{
                  enabled: true
                }} on your Swiper React component

Comment: @gauri-gattni This will not work for Mouse scroll. You need to add one more module i.e `Mousewheel` and use it like `SwiperCore.use([Keyboard, Mousewheel])`

Answer (score 6):

**This works for me perfectly.**

```
import SwiperCore, { Keyboard, Mousewheel } from "swiper/core";

SwiperCore.use([Keyboard, Mousewheel]);

const App = () => {

  const slides = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  return (
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView={2}
      keyboard={true}
      direction="vertical"
      mousewheel={true}
    >
      {slides.map((slide) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={slide}>
          <h1>Slide</h1>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks @Sandeep Sihari works for me 
:
```js
              slidesPerView={1}
              spaceBetween={1}
              centeredSlides={false}
              observer={true}
              observeParents={true}
              keyboard={true}
              direction="horizontal"
              mousewheel={true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution but for anyone interested I have come up with a work around.

I was unable to get the mouse-wheel or keyboard controls to work for Swiper using React components or with pure javascript. Official Swiper examples didn't work when replicated so I tried some previous versions. Went all the way back to 5.4.5 to get it work.

Unfortunately 5.4.5 doesn't support React but Swiper can still be incorporated into a React setup.

```js
// import Swiper JS
import Swiper from "swiper/js/swiper";
// import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css/swiper.css";

const SimpleSwiper = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      direction: "vertical",
      mousewheel: true,
      keyboard: { enabled: true },
      slidesPerView: 1,
    });
  }, []);

  const slides = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <div className="swiper-container">
      <div className="swiper-wrapper">
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <div
            className="swiper-slide"
            key={slide}
          >{`slide ${slide}`}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can view the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-vertical-mousewheel-solution-79q8i?file=/src/index.js). The keyboard control doesn't seem to work here but it does work locally.